# Accurate evaluation of function for negative x

Tags: python, precision, numeric

Is there a way to accurately evaluate `f(x)` as given below for moderate negative x (around -1e6 to -1e2), while sticking with float64 numbers?

```py
def f(x):
    return 0.5 + arctan(x/sqrt(3)) / pi + sqrt(3)*x/(pi*(x*x+3))
```

For example:

```py
g(-10_000) == 1.1026577511479050e-12  # actual closest float64 (what I want)
f(-10_000) == 1.1026461116240595e-12  # current implementation
#                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- wrong
```

Comment: How did you determine what the closest float64 was? Perhaps you could reverse-engineer it.

Comment: I used `mpmath`  (an arbitrary precision lib) & checked against WolframAlpha - unfortunately it's about 1,000x slower, and was hoping for something more efficient (e.g. maybe a 10x).

Comment: @`hbwales` : for starters, you're calculating the same `sqrt(3)` twice, and it's a constant anyway….. or, if you don't mind hard-coded numeric constants, pre-calculate `1/sqrt(3)`, `1/pi`, and `sqrt(3)/pi` to sufficient precision, and hard code those constants into your code, and switch those 2 of those division ops to a multiply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```py
def g(x):
    # approximation to f(x)
    # method: For x<0 we have the identity: atan(x) === -pi/2 - atan(1/x)
    # substitute this into f(x) then expand about -infinity, simplify & truncate
    assert x <= -100
    k = 3**0.5 / (pi * x)
    y = -3.0/(x*x)
    return k*y*(2/3 + y*(4/5 + y*(6/7 + y*(8/9 + y*10/11))))
```

This keeps the relative error below ~3e-16 for the range I'm interested in and has about the same performance, or even a little faster:

| x | rel_err(f) | rel_err(g) | abs_err(f) | abs_err(g) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | -2.012e-11 | -2.774e-16 | -2.217e-17 | -3.058e-22 |
| -1,000 | -5.660e-08 | -4.603e-18 | -6.241e-17 | -5.076e-27 |
| -10,000 | -1.056e-05 | -1.571e-16 | -1.164e-17 | -1.733e-28 |
| -100,000 | -6.418e-02 | -2.529e-17 | -7.077e-17 | -2.789e-32 |
| -1,000,000 | -4.585e+01 | -9.824e-17 | -5.056e-17 | -1.083e-34 |